# how to return a string with findstr in windows with matching substring

Tags: regex, findstr

I have a string in a file like,

```
async.AsyncTranslationThread - processPart: Finished Processing job number: J215577 partID: 151269
```

any many more.

I want to return only that line which has substring **Finished Processing job number**

I wrote a findstr command with regex like

```
findstr /R "^.*Finished\sProcessing\sjob\snumber.*$" filename
```

I am getting nothing in return, what would be the change in regex to get the string with substring in it?

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please accept it to mark the question as closed :)

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732459(v=ws.10)), `findstr` doesn't support most traditional regex features, such as `\s`, which you are using. It doesn't even support the `+` quantifier!

> The following table lists the metacharacters that findstr accepts.
>
> ```
> | Meta Character | Value
> | .              | Wildcard: any character
> | *              | Repeat: zero or more occurrences of the previous character or class
> | ^              | Line position: beginning of the line
> | $              | Line position: end of the line
> | [class]        | Character class: any one character in a set
> | [^class]       | Inverse class: any one character not in a set
> | [x-y]          | Range: any characters within the specified range
> | \x             | Escape: literal use of a metacharacter x
> | \<string       | Word position: beginning of the word
> | string\>       | Word position: end of the word
> ```

You can easily get away with this, and it'll still accept it if even there are multiple spaces or tabs:

```
findstr /c:"Finished Processing job number" filename
```

Furthermore, it seems that it's not even case sensitive by default

Comment: this will match single word as well. I want to have only the line which has all this word in it.

Comment: @LaxmiKadariya Sorry, I missed an option - `/c:<string>` - `Uses the specified text as a literal search string.`